# Find element in subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm quite new to the field of set theory. 
I have $n$ sets, so that $S_1 \cup S_2 \cup ... \cup S_n = \bigcup_{j=1}^n S_j$. 
Now, I would like to find the subset $s_j$ that contains some element $e \in S_j$. In other words, I would like to get the index of the $j$'th subset, that contains $e$. Is this even possible to express?

I have the feeling, that my problem might be connected to this: [subset of element](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1959261/subset-of-element) but I don't get my head around it.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a unique such $j$ for every such $e$? That is, are the $S_j$ disjoint?

Comment: Yes, the sets are disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

Given $e$, 
$$\{\,i\in\Bbb N\mid e\in S_i\,\} $$
is $\{j\}$ if $e\in S_j$. To ontain $j$ itself, we can use
$$\bigcup \{\,i\in\Bbb N\mid e\in S_i\,\}.$$